# setup ROR application using puma nginx and capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano, puma

I'm trying to deploy ruby on rails application to the Amazon EC2 instance, using puma as an application server, nginx server and capistrano for deployments. Currently I'm stuck with the error message:

[image]

nginx logs are not showing any error,

puma logs are also not showing what's the error

I have verified that puma server is started and running, using the following command:

```
ubuntu@ip-nnnnn:~$ ps aux | grep puma
deployer   89555  0.0  1.5 652040 248180 ?       Sl   21:48   0:00 puma 3.12.1 (unix://nnnn/nnn/current/tmp/sockets/puma.sock) [20211130214658]
deployer   89561  0.0  1.5 854804 259336 ?       Sl   21:48   0:00 puma: cluster worker 0: 89555 [20211130214658]
deployer   89566  0.0  1.5 787216 247824 ?       Sl   21:48   0:00 puma: cluster worker 1: 89555 [20211130214658]
ubuntu     89845  0.0  0.0   8168   740 pts/0    S+   22:23   0:00 grep --color=auto puma
```

capistrano deploys without any error, all tasks are completed fine, the puma server is restarted fine during the capistrano deployment.

application log has no recent data, it looks like it doesn't reach to that point, it breaks before that.

Comment: Maybe you can try to deploy in `development` mode instead of `production` so it will show the development error page with more details instead of that one. Though from that screenshot there should be something in the app's log/ directory

Comment: @arieljuod the application is deployed in the `development` mode. Do you know what setting should I change to see the detailed error page?

Comment: @arieljuod, after some googling it appears that I need to set `config.consider_all_requests_local = true` to see the complete error details page.

Comment: Deployments are not made in any mode. Capistrano scripts determine how your deployment is made. it is the way that the rails server is run that determines the mode that your application is being run in and you should definitely be running your rails server in production mode not development mode on your production server. Anything else is madness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my particular case it was due to the stopped REDIS service. The application was configured to utilize REDIS for caching, however REDIS service wasn't running. This wasn't reflected in the logs for some reason and I spent a good amount of time figuring out what was wrong.